# Extend existing interface with new properties without declaring new interface

Tags: typescript

Lets assume I have interface:

```
interface Cat {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  color: string;
}
```

And now I want to create object with new interface that is extending partial Cat with new properties:

```
interface MyCat extends Partial<Cat> {
  sex: "male" | "female"
}
const cat: MyCat = {name: "Tom", sex: "male"}
```

Thus it works. But what if I don't want to declare new interface(MyCat) in case I will not reuse it anywhere and I want to do something like this (set type when I am creating object):

```
const cat: Partial<Cat> {sex: "male" | "female"} = {name: "Tom", sex: "male"}
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you're very close, just missing an `&`:

`const cat: Partial<Cat> & {sex: "male" | "female"} = {name: "Tom", sex: "male"}`